# Flex, how to close a few alert by escape?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an issue when a few alerts is opened. I am able to close last alert by esc after that I am not able to close other alerts by esc. I would like to close all alerts by one pressing esc or when I press esc it should close last alert and will focus on previous alert, so I will be able to close it by pressing esc.

Just example:

```
Alert.show("some text", "alert1");
Alert.show("different text", "alert2");
```

Not able to close alert1 by esc.

Comment: You really didn't bother reading the docs. First of all Alert is not supposed to be used to create a bunch of Alert on top of each other but if you must do so keep a reference of it: var alert:Alert = Alert.show(etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good idea here would be to use the popupManager to show your messages i think.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html

Doing so will allow you to interact with your popups more efficiently